# Add multiple MVC to a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, model-view-controller, uiscrollview

Is it possible to add MVC to an `UIScrollView`?

Currently i dragged three `UIView's` from the button category and put them inside the scroll view hierarchy, does the `UIView's` get stacked on top of each other instead of pushing them out on each side? I wrote some code but that did not do anything for now, for now i am wondering if it is possible to add MVC to the `UIScrollView` and how can i do that?

Swift language preferred.

note: i am new to xcode and would like to get some tips on where to learn some basics about different view controllers and using `MKMapKit` with GeoLocation if possible!

Comment: MVC is a design pattern. It is not a UIElement. If you are talking about adding a UIViewController to ScrollVIew, then NO. You can only add UIView to the scrollView!!!!

Comment: what do u mean by button category ? Do you mean by object library  that is in the xcode ?

Comment: And how do I add UIView to the scrollView? Yes the object library @Mr.T